# Tensorflow Hub Module's trainable variables are not updated during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, transfer-learning, tensorflow-hub

My question is quite similar to one asked here: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/269. But those question remains unanswered, so I will ask it here. Steps to reproduce:

> tensorflow           1.14.0 tensorflow-hub       0.5.0 Python 3.7.4
>   Windows 10

Here is the sample notebook with the problem reproduced:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PKUyoQRP3othu6cu7v7N7yn8K2pjkuKP

1. Load a tensor_hub Inception 3 module as trainable:

```py
    module_spec = hub.load_module_spec('https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_v3/feature_vector/3')
    height, width = hub.get_expected_image_size(module_spec)
        with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
            resized_input_tensor =  tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, 3])
            module = hub.Module(module_spec, trainable=True, tags={"train"})  
            bottleneck_tensor = module(inputs=dict(images=resized_input_tensor, batch_norm_momentum=0.997),signature="image_feature_vector_with_bn_hparams")
```

2. Save all the Trainable/Model/Global variables created at this moment to separate 'base model' lists (3 lists)
   Example of vars:
   *base_model trainable_variables vars*: 188, ['module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights:0', 'module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/beta:0'..
   *base_model model_variables vars*: 188, ['module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/moving_mean:0', 'module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/moving_variance:0
   *base_model variables vars*: 0, [] #empty list
3. Add a custom classification layer on top of model:

```py
    batch_size, previous_tensor_size = bottleneck_tensor.get_shape().as_list()
    ground_truth_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.int64, [batch_size], name='GroundTruthInput')
    initial_value = tf.random.truncated_normal([previous_tensor_size, class_count], stddev=0.001)
    layer_weights = tf.Variable(initial_value, name='final_weights')
    layer_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([class_count]), name='final_biases')
    logits = tf.matmul(hidden_layer, layer_weights) + layer_biases
    final_tensor = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=final_tensor_name)
```

4. Again, get all newly added variable names into 3 new different 'Custom' lists:

   custom trainable_variables vars: 2, ['final_weights:0', 'final_biases:0']
   custom model_variables vars: 0, []
   custom variables vars: 0, []
5. Add train operation. Because of base model has batch normalization, we have to care about update ops. That is why I use tf.contrib.training.create_train_op:

```py
    cross_entropy_all = tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=ground_truth_input, logits=logits)
    optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer()

    #the update ops are set to the contents of the tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS collection.
    #variables to train will default to all tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables().
    train_step = tf.contrib.training.create_train_op(cross_entropy_mean, optimizer)
```

6. 4. Again, get all newly added variable names into 3 new different 'Optimizer' lists:
      optimizer trainable_variables vars: 0, []
      optimizer model_variables vars: 0, []
      optimizer variables vars: 383, ['global_step:0', 'beta1_power:0', 'beta2_power:0', 'module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights/Adam:0', 'module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights/Adam_1:0', 'module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/beta/Adam:0', 'module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1:0', 'module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_2a_3x3/weights/Adam:0', 'module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_2a_3x3/weights/Adam_1:0', 'module/InceptionV3/Conv2d_2a_3x3/BatchNorm/beta/Adam:0',...

Now do the regular training:

```py
    with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
        # Initialize all weights: for the module to their pretrained values,
        # and for the newly added retraining layer to random initial values.
        init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)

        #dump the checkssum for all the variables lists collected during graph building

        for i in range(1000):
            # Get a batch of input resized images values, calculated fresh
            (train_data, train_ground_truth) = get_random_batch_data(sess, image_lists....)

            #dump the checksum for all the variables lists collected during graph building


            # Feed the input placeholder and ground truth into the graph, and run a training
            # step.
            sess.run([train_step], feed_dict = {
                resized_input_tensor: train_data,
                ground_truth_input: train_ground_truth})

            #dump now again the checksum for all the variables lists collected during graph building
```

So, after the each training step the checksum is changed only for the two variable lists, custom trainable and optimizer global:

```
    base_model trainable_variables, 2697202.0, cf4682249fc1f48e9a346149f84e503d unchanged
    base_model model_variables,
        2936996.0, 6f995f5f0f032604a49a96ceec576cf7 unchanged
    base_model variables, 0, d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e unchanged
    custom trainable_variables, -0.7915199408307672, 889c333a56b9496d412eacdcbeb3bef1 **changed**
    custom model_variables, 0, d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e unchanged
    custom variables, 0, d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e unchanged
    optimizer trainable_variables, 0, d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e unchanged
    optimizer model_variables, 0, d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e unchanged
    optimizer variables,
        5580902.81437762, d2cb2d4b253a1c12452f560eea35ac42 **changed**
```

So, the question is, why base model's **Trainable variables** have not been changed ??
They are BatchNorm/moving_mean, BatchNorm/moving_variance, Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights, which definitely should be updated during training. Even more, moving_variance also should be changed, because UPDATE_OPS are included as dependency for the train step inside the tf.contrib.training.create_train_op call. I've checked the UPDATE_OPS list, it contains valid values like:
Update ops:
tf.Operation 'module_apply_image_feature_vector_with_bn_hparams/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/AssignMovingAvg/AssignSubVariableOp' type=AssignSubVariableOp>,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after deep debugging of a issue I found that the problem is in following:
just getting the variable from a global variable list and getting it's value using eval() on it is not enough: it will return some value but it is not current (at least this is what happening for the variables of imported model with dtype=resource).

To calculate current value we have to get first a value tensor using variable.**value()** or variable.**read_value()** and doing **eval()** for it (for the returned 'value' tensor).

This resolves the question.